# TextField loses focus after a single character entry

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have this code of a simple ToDo app.
Tasks are rendered inside a List Foreach loop like so.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {    
    @State var tasks: [Entry] = []
    @State var showTasks: Bool = false
    @State var entryText: String = ""
    @State var entryChecked: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10)
        {
            List{
                ForEach($tasks, id: \.self){
                    i in
                    EntryView(entry: i)
                }
            }
            Form {
                Section("Add a new Entry"){
                    HStack {
                        Toggle("Done", isOn: $entryChecked).labelsHidden()
                        Divider()
                        Spacer()
                        TextField("Enter:", text: $entryText)
                    }
                    Button("Submit"){
                        tasks.append(Entry(checked: entryChecked, task: entryText))
                    }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
                    Button("Print Tasks"){
                        showTasks.toggle()
                        print(tasks)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            tasks.append(Entry(checked: true, task: "Say Hi"))
            tasks.append(Entry(checked: false, task: "And Fuck You"))
            tasks.append(Entry(checked: false, task: "Bye Bye"))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Entry: Hashable, Equatable, Identifiable {
     var id = UUID()
     var checked: Bool = false
     var task: String = ""
}

struct EntryView: View {
    @Binding var entry: Entry
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Toggle("Done", isOn: self.$entry.checked).labelsHidden()
            Divider()
            Spacer()
            TextField("Enter:", text: self.$entry.task)
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I enter a single tap in the upper section it loses focus, can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?
My guess is that the view is rendering the List because the state has changed as I input a single character, can I defer that until I submit my edit or enter Enter in Mac

Comment: change `.self` to `.id`                 `ForEach($tasks, id: \.id){`

Comment: @loremipsum That worked alright, I really would love to know how that's the case, id vs self

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022